# Upgrade my server or migrate it to a new server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016, windows-server

I have a two servers, one is application server that runs with Windows Server 2003 and one SQL server runs with SQL 2008 and windows server 2003 OS. I would like to upgrade the both servers' OS to Windows Server 2012 and the SQL server to use SQL 2016.

My understanding is that I can just upgrade the OS and the SQL server, but my IT said we need to buy new servers with new OS and new SQL server version and then migrate from the old to new ones.

Just ask which way is better?

Thank you

Comment: Why only upgrade to Windows Server 2012? It's already 2 versions old?

Comment: Do you actually have a license which allows upgrades for Windows Server and for SQL Server. Having said that.. go for Windows Server 2016 or stay with 2008 R2. I find 2012 with the Windows 8 menu rather painful. Buying new servers is a usual procedure for IT shops which use OEM licenses and require a valid support contract for servers.

Comment: All answers are pretty helpful, I choose the one that fits my situation better, thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, most people recommend migration over an in-place upgrade to move to a new SQL Server version.

It's a matter of risk reduction. You can set everything up on the new server, and confirm that none of the changes in the new version break your existing applications. If you do run into problems, you can work them out before you go live on the new SQL Server version, rather than risk having your production system down for an unknown amount of time.

That said, you can get much the same effect by setting up an instance of the new version and testing there. There is still some risk if you do this on your production server, in that the resources used by the new version's instance are not available to the current production instance, so you may cause the production instance and applications some problems.

Actually, best practice would be to make sure the test instance of the new SQL version is running on the new target OS version as well; otherwise, you could run into OS-related issues that you're not expecting, because you tested with the old OS.

NOTE: this is in addition to the potential hardware issues raised in indiri's answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good chance this question will be closed due to '[primarily opinion-based](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)' and a lot depends on your individual circumstances, but here's mine...

I think you'll be better off going with fresh new servers with the latest OS and Sql Server versions you can tolerate.

You'll be able to do side by side testing between the old current environment and the new one in a more leisurely pace and minimize the risk of things going south due to a buggy upgrade.

Before you make your decision, I'd like to share an article by **Michael K. Campbell** entitled [Reasons to Avoid SQL Server In-Place Upgrades](http://sqlmag.com/blog/reasons-avoid-sql-server-place-upgrades).  Following are his arguments against in-place upgrades. (I'm basically copying the entire article because I think he's '***spot-on***'.)

**Gremlins**

> Call me nuts, paranoid, or just plain crazy, but I simply don't trust
>   Windows or SQL Server installations. Yes, most of the time, they go
>   completely as expected. But upgrades commonly bump into ugly problems.
>   And if we're talking about production workloads, running into one of
>   the random problems that can crop up when trying to run an upgrade on
>   a production server can be insanely expensive—not just in terms of
>   additional downtime, but also potentially in terms of your
>   credibility.
>
> Furthermore, even if you want to argue that an in-place upgrade where
>   you reformat the server back to bare metal, spin up a new OS, and then
>   install SQL Server (the new version) over the top of your old hardware
>   (after grabbing db backups, etc.) can work, I'll still argue against
>   such an approach. First of all, I've seen too many strange or weird
>   cases where the installation of either Windows Server or SQL Server
>   just doesn't take correctly. Yes, those instances are increasingly
>   rare. But, when we're talking about a production workload, I almost
>   never find the potential risk to be acceptable. Furthermore, even if
>   you delude yourself into thinking that you can practice or rehearse
>   the upgrade process, you're doing that in a controlled environment and
>   not against the actual hardware or metal where a driver problem or
>   issue might crop up.
>
> Instead, I find that it's much easier and effective to stand up a new
>   replacement host, configure it without any stress or duress (i.e.,
>   without worrying about a ticking clock counting down to when you need
>   to be back online or running), and double-check all best practices and
>   security configurations, and the like. Then, you can just copy
>   security information (such as logins, etc.) on to the server and load
>   on copies of your databases (i.e., via backups) to then start pointing
>   application servers at this old/stale data to begin acceptance
>   testing. Then, once you're sure everything is working correctly, you
>   can just schedule a time to take the current production server down
>   and switch over to the new server. And, if something goes wrong during
>   that transition (as long as you haven't started writing data to the
>   new location), then you can always abort your migration and switch
>   back to the old server and try again another time. Whereas, if you try
>   an in-place upgrade and something goes wrong, then, well, you're
>   screwed and are stuck scrambling to get something back up and running.

**Artifacts**

> If we assume that gremlins represent show-stopper or fatal problems
>   that completely thwart upgrades, then what about something even worse?
>   Like, something that fails to upgrade or install correctly as part of
>   your upgrade—but which you don't detect right away. Then, imagine the
>   cost (in terms of pain/manageability) of having to workaround that
>   issue more or less indefinitely. While such artifacts are rare, the
>   costs they impose ensure that they're something you want to avoid like
>   the plague. And while you CAN miss these kinds of issues or problems
>   when you stand-up a brand new server to replace your old server, my
>   experience is that you have much more time and ability to test and
>   interact with this server (and hopefully, therefore, find such
>   problems or issues) as opposed to being in a serious hurry to get core
>   functionality up when doing an in-place upgrade.

**Missing out on Hardware Improvements**

> If you're upgrading to a new version of SQL Server, it's likely been
>   about 2-3 years since your previous host was provisioned. Hardware
>   capabilities have, effectively, doubled in that time. And the size and
>   demands of your workloads have likely increased over that same time—so
>   attempting to upgrade on the same/old hardware can and will work (each
>   new version of SQL Server usually picks up around a 15-20 percent
>   performance boost due to increased efficiencies in the underlying
>   engine)—but just doesn't make as much sense as upgrading to new
>   hardware.
>
> Of course, while that argument makes instant sense to tech heads, it
>   doesn't always make great sense to bean-counters (i.e., if your CIO or
>   manager comes from a background more related to bean counting. or, if
>   funds are sparse, then hardware benefits and improvements alone might
>   not be enough to justify). Still, I'll always argue that disruptions
>   caused by anything listed above also come with costs (which can
>   sometimes be unacceptably costly in terms of negative user
>   interactions or linger maintenance costs), and that new hardware is
>   almost always worth it. Besides, when you take this approach, it's not
>   like you throw away your old production hosts when you're done. The
>   old production hosts can easily be repurposed for other tasks (for
>   other workloads) or can be reused as staging or dev servers, if
>   they're still in decent-enough working order.

**Testing**

> Unless you're just assuming that you can do an in-place upgrade and
>   everything will work—which is just plain dumb—then you're going to
>   need to spin up some sort of additional host or server to act as a
>   testing server that you can use to see how your applications behave
>   when they've been upgraded.
>
> In other words, if you're going to go through this effort anyhow (and
>   you really would be stupid not to), then WHY test this on anything BUT
>   the new hardware where you're going to actually be hosting your
>   databases going forward? In other words, with an in-place upgrade,
>   you're going to have to go 'fake' an upgrade/testing environment, and
>   then, you'll just assume that everything you tested and validated
>   there will work on your current/production hardware after you
>   magically manage to upgrade that hardware without any issues. Whereas,
>   if you perform a side-by-side upgrade, not only are you removing the
>   guess work, but you can also actually put your new hardware under load
>   (in many cases) to fully verify how it will behave.

**Downtime**

> Another great benefit of side-by-side upgrades is that you can
>   decrease downtime. In fact, with enough preparation and staging (along
>   with rehearsals when/where needed), you can actually upgrade in 5
>   minutes or less. With in-place upgrades, you're forced to wait while a
>   Wizard churns along and upgrades various components, databases,
>   binaries, and the like. But with a side-by-side migration, you can
>   verify that the new server is configured and working as needed, then
>   load copies of recent FULL backups on to the box, restore (but not
>   recover them), and then just keep applying T-Logs through the day (or
>   use DIFFs + T-Log backups if that makes more sense). Then, you've got
>   a warm spare configuration so that when your maintenance window
>   arrives, you can just shut down the current production host, take
>   tail-of-the log backups, and then apply them to your new server and
>   then spin up your applications (with connection strings pointing at
>   the new server) after recovering the database. All in all, very easy
>   to handle, very easy to practice and rehearse, and very easy to pull
>   off with minimal down-time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it depends.  How does your current hardware compare to the requirements for Windows Server 2012/SQL 2016. It's possible that the old hardware can't run it and that's why he is saying you have to migrate. If it does meet requirements, have you had any issues with the hardware? How old is it?  All of these things can factor in to whether you need to get a new server or if you can simply upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on SQL part only as this is my area. I always encourage people to do upgrade by migration as this approach gives several benefits (some have already been mentioned)

First of all, you are migrating from relatively old version. You will have to make sure both, the functional and non functional sides of the SQL code-base run on the new platform without issues. You will likely use Upgrade Assistant to find any deprecated syntax that may no longer work and you will also want to establish performance baseline to filter out any post-migration performance problems.

Secondly, having both, the new and old online will allow you to keep them in sync in order to run parallel testing and filter out any existing problems, not caused by the upgrade. This will approach will also allow you to minimize downtime required for the migration by utilizing log shipping for example.

And most importantly, having old instance will give you a clean fail back in case you have to roll back. Imagine once you have started upgrading your only production instance, something goes wrong and you are left with nothing. The only back out is either go back to back ups or VM snapshots. Why risk it?